# How can I claim or refund expired claimable balance?

Tags: stellar-core

If any wallet have expired claimable balance, how can be proceeded?
If not proceeded, reserves will be remaining for sending address
Are there solving methods for it?

Thanks for advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing can be done afterward.

A best practice is to set the sender as a claimant as well, this allows the sender to claim the balance back if the recipient didn't claim it himself before the expiration.

Comment: The sponsor (which can be different from the sender) needs to sponsor the claimants as long as a CB is not claimed. And therefore yes: expired CBs need to be sponsored eternally.